# Using the Root or Ratio test determine if series diverges or converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Using the Root or Ratio test determine if series diverges or converges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$$

I tried root test and rise it to the 1/n:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{1/2n}}$$

but I don't know how to proceed from here. Most probably root test is inconclusive but I need to show it and then use some other test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't proceed from here using the root test or the ratio test. They're both inconclusive, since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac1{\sqrt n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\frac1{\sqrt n}}=1.$$However, your series diverges by the comparison test:$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\frac1{\sqrt n}\geqslant\frac1n$$and the harmonic series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

For any $m$,

$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{\sqrt n}
\ge m\frac{1}{\sqrt m}
=\sqrt{m}
\to \infty
$.